# http call not triggering in promise callback angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable, angular2-http

In my angular 2 project I make this call to get some data:

```
this.http.getfromgraphql()
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

This triggers the getfromgraphql function shown below, before I make that call though, I have to check if the access token is still valid in checkaccesstokenvalidity, there I set some variables and resolve the function.
the console logs 'in then' but my http post does not trigger.
Why is that?
Also, I am sure there is a better way to do this, but for the life of me I can't figure it out, a better solution is much appreciated

```
checkAccessTokenValidity() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    // if(!this.access_token) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.URL + 'oauth/token', this.authentication, options)
        .subscribe(function(response) {
            this.authObj = response.json();
            this.expirationDate = new Date();
            this.expirationDate.setSeconds(this.expirationDate.getSeconds() + this.authObj.expires_in);
            console.log(this.authObj, this.expirationDate);
          },
          error => console.log("Error: ", error),
          function() {
            console.log('resolving');
            resolve();
          });

    });
    // }
  }
  getfromgraphql() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.checkAccessTokenValidity().then(function() {
      console.log('in then');
      //noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
      return this.http.post(this.URL + '/api/v1/graphql', this.query, options);
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you using the function `getfromgraphql ()`?

Comment: I call getfromgraphql from some component using this.http.getfromgraphql() then that function gets a new access token from checkaccesstokenvalidity() after that it makes a post to endpoint /api/v1/graphql but that doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Point 1:

Do not use `function(){}` in any of your callbacks. Assuming you are using Typescript (or ES6 for that matter), you are not using `lexical` this. All of your `this` will have a reference to the inner scope. You will get lots of undefined. Use fat arrow notations `()=>{}`.

#### Point 2:

Since you are already using `Observables` in all of your methods, continue to use them (reactive programming) and stay away from using `Promise` unless necessary.

In your `getfromgraphql()` method, simply use a `flatMap()`. It is the same as `.then()` in promise.

Also, in resolving the error, simply do a `.catch()` if needed. Observables will propagate the error to the highest caller.

```
checkAccessTokenValidity() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(this.URL + 'oauth/token', this.authentication, options)
        .map(response => {
            this.authObj = response.json();
            this.expirationDate = new Date();
            this.expirationDate.setSeconds(this.expirationDate.getSeconds() + this.authObj.expires_in);
            console.log(this.authObj, this.expirationDate);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.empty();
        })
}

getfromgraphql() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.checkAccessTokenValidity().flatMap(()=>{
        console.log('in then');
        //noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
        return this.http.post(this.URL + '/api/v1/graphql', this.query, options);
    })
}
```

Comment: this gives me the error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. on calling this.http.getfromgraphql()
      .subscribe(response=> {
          console.log(response);
        });

Comment: @dennismuys sorry, you need to return the observables. see the edit

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you are doing `this.http.getfromgraphql()` but for other 
code in reactive way its like this :

```
checkAccessTokenValidity() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
               .post(this.URL + 'oauth/token', this.authentication, options)
               .map(response => {
                   this.authObj = response.json();
                   this.expirationDate
                      .setSeconds((new Date())
                      .getSeconds() + this.authObj.expires_in);
               });
      }

getfromgraphql() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.checkAccessTokenValidity()
        .switchMap(token =>  this.http
               .post(this.URL + '/api/v1/graphql', this.query, options)   
 }
```

And the way you call this method is

```
someService.getfromgraphql()
           .subscribe(response=> {
// ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your post call with this :

```
return this.http.post(this.URL + '/api/v1/graphql', this.query, options).subscribe(() => {});
```

and see if it works now.

Comment: it makes no difference fahad

Comment: hm. Can you provide plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, { name }, options)
       .toPromise()
```

or add a resolve() in your subscribe

```
 .subscribe(function(response) {
        this.authObj = response.json();
        this.expirationDate = new Date();
        this.expirationDate.setSeconds(this.expirationDate.getSeconds() + 
        this.authObj.expires_in);
        console.log(this.authObj, this.expirationDate);
        resolve();
      },
```

and instead of resolve in error you can use reject() in your error body

following plunker will help you
https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview
check for hero.service.promise.ts in app/toh folder

Comment: that plunker seems to be empty